# Disable text field for tab key press event in extjs

Tags: extjs4, textfield

How to disable a text field only while pressing tab key from keyboard in extjs?

Answer (score 2):

You can set `enableKeyEvents` property of the textfield to true, then detect the `tab` `keypress` and disable your textfield:

```
{
   xtype: 'textfield',
   ...
   enableKeyEvents: true,
   listeners : {
      keypress : function(textfield, e, options) {
         if (e.keyCode == 9) {
            textfield.setDisabled(true);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you set the tabIndex config of the textfield to a negative value, the textfield can't be reached with the tab key.
Example:

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    title: 'Contact Info',
    width: 300,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    items: [{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        name: 'name',
        fieldLabel: 'Name',
        tabIndex: 1
    }, {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        name: 'email',
        fieldLabel: 'Email Address',
        tabIndex: -1
    }]
});
```

In this example, the email textfield can't be reached by pressing the tab key.